# Android - ListView - playlist

Tags: android, listview, media-player

I am making an audio player, i need to browse files/folders from device and add them to playlist (ListView). The most important for me is to UNDERSTAND what is going on, and how to do this. I think i need to get filenames and fill the ListView with it, but don't know how. Second qeustion is how to play these files in the playlist? Thank you!

Comment: ... And what did you try? Show your efforts. This is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following steps

1. Query for the song, **ContentResolver** class to retrieve tracks on the device
2. Display the data extracted using **Content Resolver** in,list view.
3. Use **MediaPlayer** class to play audio and the MediaController class to
   control playback.
4. Use a **Service** instance to play audio when the user is not directly interacting with the app.

Below I have mentioned very nice tutorial by TuPlus that covers everything of your question.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764